# Laravel Validator Value Filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I Need to ask about Validator on Laravel, I need to filter Input of cardID and age, like :

cardID = "103*******" //first character must contain 103
and
age = min value = 17 yo , max value = 30 yo

my controller validator was like :

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
    array(
        'cardID' =>'required',
        'age' =>'required',
    )
);
if($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::route('user-create-account-get')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has two [validation rules](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation) for this:

```
between:min,max
```

which will be useful for your age and

```
regex:pattern
```

which will be useful for your cardID.

Comment: how to use regex:pattern? can you give example?

Comment: @GandhyOnly It uses the pattern syntax from http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php.